# Android Q SDK saving images in DCIM folder for older versions as well

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-10.0

I am working on an application in which we take screenshot and save it in the DCIM/MYFOLDER folder. My previous piece of code included Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory which was working fine.

I upgraded my SDK to support Android Q. My Compile SDK is set to Android 10.0 Q. Now this above code is shown as deprecated in my IDE and it didnt save screenshots to the specified folder. I updated my piece of code and now its working for Android 10 devices but for previous devices its not working.

I don't want to put if else statements to use two piece of code for two platforms because the previous one is deprecated in Android Q.

Here's my current code which is working for Android 10 devices but not in Android 8:

```
var screenshot = CaptureAsyncValue();

var imageName = number + ".png";

var IMAGES_FOLDER_NAME = "MYFOLDER";

ContentResolver resolver = _currentActivity.ContentResolver;

ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.Put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DisplayName, imageName);
contentValues.Put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MimeType, "image/png");
contentValues.Put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RelativePath, "DCIM/" + IMAGES_FOLDER_NAME);

// this URI variable is null for devices below Android 10 hence the next line of code crashes
Uri imageUri = resolver.Insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri, contentValues); 

var fos = resolver.OpenOutputStream(imageUri);

await fos.WriteAsync(screenshot);

fos.Flush();
fos.Close();
```

Comment: To support the latest versions of Android, the platform provides the temporarily opt-out of scoped storage feature for data storage.  Check the tutorial:https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/compatibility

Answer (score 2):

Either use `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` for backwards/forwards compatibility, or fix it properly by not requesting legacy external storage and having two different storage locations.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by having two different storage locations?

Comment: Did you try to set `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage` to true`? Does it work?

Comment: @Martin Zeitler How does Whatsapp work ? I am using Android Q and its saving images in Gallery and on pervious OS version (Android 9) They are able to save in gallery as well